# Network no longer works after replacing components on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking

The motherboard of my server (Ubuntu 8.04) died, so I replaced the motherboard, CPU, and RAM. **Now I cannot get the server working on the network as it was configured.**

The network is configured without DHCP.

The router IP is `10.10.10.1`. The server is `10.10.10.10`.

**Contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.10.10.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.10.10.1
```

**Pinging the router (`ping 10.10.10.1`) results in:**

```
PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.10.10.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.10.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
...
```

**The result of `ifconfig eth0`:**

```
eth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr  90:2b:34:a5:c9:af
         inet addr:10.10.10.10 Bcast: 10.10.10.255  Mask: 255.255.255.0
         inet6 addr: fe80... ( skipped typing this )
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
         RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overrruns: 0 frame:0
         TX packets:446 errors:0 dropped:0 overrruns: 0 carrier:0
         collisions: 0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:o (0.0 B)  TX bytes:32324 (31.5kb)
         Interrupt:220 Base address:0xa00
```

**The result of `route`:**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway         Genmask                Flags   Metric   Ref   Use   iFace
10.10.10.0     *               255.255.255.0          U       0        0       0   eth0
link-local     *               255.255.0.0            U       1000     0       0   eth0
default        10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0                UG      100      0       0   eth0
```

(Note: The first two results appear immediately. The last line (default route) appears after about 20 seconds. If I do `route -n` all results show immediately.)

The result of `iptables -L` shows that there are no iptables entries.

**The contents of `/etc/hostname`:**

```
Server
```

**The contents of `/etc/hosts`:**

```
127.0.0.1        localhost.localdomain localhost
10.10.10.10      Server.localdomain Server

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

**Result of `mii-tool`:**

```
SIOCGMIIPHY on `eth0` failed: Operation not supported
SIOCGMIIPHY on `eth1` failed: Operation not supported
SIOCGMIIPHY on `eth2` failed: Operation not supported
SIOCGMIIPHY on `eth3` failed: Operation not supported
SIOCGMIIPHY on `eth4` failed: Operation not supported
SIOCGMIIPHY on `eth5` failed: Operation not supported
SIOCGMIIPHY on `eth6` failed: Operation not supported
SIOCGMIIPHY on `eth7` failed: Operation not supported
no MII interfaces found
```

**Result of `sudo mii-tool`:**

```
SIOCGMIIPHY on `eth0` failed: Operation not supported
no MII interfaces found
```

**Result of `arp -a`:**

```
? (10.10.10.1) at <incomplete> on eth0
```

**Result of `dmesg | grep eth0`:**

```
[    22.188268] eth0: RTL8169 at 0xf8888000, 90:2b:34:a5:c9:af, XID 2c900800 IRQ 220
[    41.919804] r8169: eth0: link up
```

I have disabled IPv6 as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebBrowsingSlowIPv6IPv4) because dmesg *was* complaining:

```
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

I have tried a different network cable and router port. Other computers on the network are functioning fine (they also have static IPs in the 10.10.10.x range).

Initially the network device was named eth2. I deleted `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` which was successfully regenerated and the new NIC was left with the desired `eth0` name. Thanks for the suggestion, Heis Spiter.

Any ideas would be a great help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the old r8169 driver and installing the latest r8168 did the trick.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Is the network card you are using integrated in the motherboard?

So, has it been replaced?

If yes, check you udev net rules: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. You might need to update your network cards naming. Removing the old network card and switching the new as eth0. The network cards are identified by their MAC address.

Comment: I already did that in order to achieve `eth0` (which was the name of the previous onboard NIC.) Excellent suggestion though - thanks.

Comment: Not sure it will really help, but, what if you try to pointopoint to your gateway in network config?

Comment: Tried that (specified `network` and `gateway` in `/etc/network/interfaces`) too. No luck. Keep up the suggestions though - you're sure to get it sooner or later! :)